# How to get sum of input fields in Angularjs and the sum need to assign to a variable?

Tags: html, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jgTN.png)

Here I have a dynamically generated table rows, in this I have to calculate sum of inputs each row and need to assign to a variable. Right now in the HTML I am able to sum but I need to assign to some variable send to the API.

Here is my HTML code:

```js
$scope.productids = ['111', '222', '333', '444', '5555'];
$scope.targets = [{
  'pid': '',
  'week1': '',
  'week2': '',
  'week3': '',
  'week4': '',
  'total': ''
}];
$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  $scope.targets.push({
    'pid': '',
    'week1': '',
    'week2': '',
    'week3': '',
    'week4': '',
    'total': ''
  });
};

$scope.removeChoice = function(val) {
  console.log("index------>", val);
  $scope.targets.splice(val, 1);
};
```

```css
thead th {
  background: rgba(13, 3, 3, 0.05);
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Id</th>
      <th>week1</th>
      <th>week2</th>
      <th>week3</th>
      <th>week4</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="target in targets">
      <td align="center">
        <select class="form-control" style="width: 170px;border: 1px solid skyblue;" data-ng-model="target.pid" ng-change="getUnitsofProduct(target.pid)">
           <option value="">Select pid</option>
           <option data-ng-repeat="pid in productids">{{pid}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input class="form-control" style="width: 70px" type="text" name="" ng-model="target.week1"> {{units}}
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input class="form-control" style="width: 70px" type="text" name="" ng-model="target.week2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input class="form-control" style="width: 70px" type="text" name="" ng-model="target.week3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input class="form-control" style="width: 70px" type="text" name="" ng-model="target.week4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
         {{ (target.week1 * 1) + (target.week2 * 1)+ (target.week3 * 1)+ (target.week4 *1) }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="add" style="background-color: #008CBA;" data-ng-show="$last" data-ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button>
        <button class="add" data-ng-click="removeChoice($index)" style="background-color:#f44336;margin:0px;">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-bind for this total field :

```
<td><span ng-bind="target.week1+target.week2+target.week3+target.week4"><span></td>
```

Comment: i solved like this <input type="text" ng-model="target.total=(target.week1 * 1) + (target.week2 * 1)+ (target.week3 * 1)+ (target.week4 *1)+ (target.week5 *1)"  readonly="readonly">

Comment: yes this is also good way but you can solve this by above way if you use ng-bind for  target.week1,target.week2 ... so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input hidden field ng-model="target.total" :

`<input class="form-control" style="width: 70px" type="hidden" name="" ng-model="target.total">`

`{{ target.total = (target.week1 * 1) + (target.week2 * 1)+ (target.week3 * 1)+ (target.week4 *1) }`

Comment: if use input type="hidden" user not able to see, user should see the total

Comment: yes u r right, we can use read only attribute in text input field.

Comment: <span style="font-weight: bold;font-style: none;color: darkorchid;">{{(((((target.week1 * 1) + (target.week2 * 1)+ (target.week3 * 1)+ (target.week4 *1))-(target.monthquantity))/(target.monthquantity))*(100))}}</span>    here the precision is  going more than 3 decimals,i want show two digits after precision